# Mathematical reason beetwen two operations

Tags: operations-research

I have spent many hours trying to find out by myself, the following:

Specifically I mean the relationship between dividing a number `"n"`, between `p`, and getting the root of `"n"` with an index `"p"`, then what is the algebraic reason between both operations?

> Besides, which branch of mathematics is studying this?

Comment: what do you mean by powerful?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which "*describes the limiting behaviour of a function when the argument tend towards a particular value or infinity*".

Square root is $\mathcal{O}(x^{1/p})$ and division by a constant is $\mathcal{O}(x)$, hence their **growth rates** are clearly compared in this way.